# Are Razor pages in combination with Blazor safe from over-binding / overposting / mass-binding attacks?

Tags: security, blazor, blazor-server-side, mass-assignment, websecurity

Do I understand correctly that overposting is only an issue with classical ASP.NET Core (like explained in [this article](https://andrewlock.net/preventing-mass-assignment-or-over-posting-with-razor-pages-in-asp-net-core/)), but not with `Blazor`?

In `Blazor Server` I do things like

```
<InputText @bind-Value="person.Name" id="name" class="form-control" />
```

so I explicitely state which values shall be bound to my objects. Does this mean that in `Blazor` I don't need any kind of so called `data transfer object` to be safe from overposting attacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Blazor Server there is no POST so you are safe from overposting to begin with.

The SignalR connection should be much less hackable, it won't let you execute something  that isn't there. `@bind-Value="person.Name"` creates a lambda method under the hood, that is your exposure.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. Can you give more details (or provide a link) on the created lambda method / how the binding works, so I can also deduce myself that overposting is not possible?

Comment: Build your project, select 'Show all files' and go to `obj\debug\netcoreapp3\razor\pages\MyEditPage.g.cs`